# Mongo 2.4 : Insert document in Reduce phase (mongo map red)

Tags: mongodb

Our input is like this

```
{ _id: 1,  deviceuuid: "d1",  sessiontime: 10, timestamp = 123456789123 }
{ _id: 2,  deviceuuid: "d1",  sessiontime: 13, timestamp = 123456789129 }
{ _id: 3,  deviceuuid: "d1",  sessiontime: 15, timestamp = 123456789133 }
{ _id: 4,  deviceuuid: "d1",  sessiontime: 16, timestamp = 123456789153 }
{ _id: 5,  deviceuuid: "d1",  sessiontime: 17, timestamp = 123456789163 }
{ _id: 6,  deviceuuid: "d2",  sessiontime: 10, timestamp = 123456789123 }
{ _id: 7,  deviceuuid: "d2",  sessiontime: 13, timestamp = 123456789129 }
{ _id: 8,  deviceuuid: "d2",  sessiontime: 15, timestamp = 123456789133 }
{ _id: 9,  deviceuuid: "d2",  sessiontime: 16, timestamp = 123456789153 }
{ _id: 10,  deviceuuid: "d2",  sessiontime: 17, timestamp = 123456789163 }
```

We are receiving “session time” fact in cumulative. So our requirement is to calculate delta and put in different collection

In Map phase:
 I am emitting key: `< deviceuuid>` and value: `{ sessiontime:<value>, timestamp=<value>}`

In Reduce phase:
I am sorting the values by timestamp and calculating the delta

```
 e.g. for device uuid “d1”
10 -0 => 10
13 -10 => 3
15 -13 => 2
16 -15 => 1
17 -16 => 1
```

We need to insert above data in different collection but db object is not available in reduce phase 
i.e.

```
db.result.save(..)  Giving error in reduce phase
```

Please suggest!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do any modifications in any collection neither in map nor in reduce phases. Only thing you could do is to save whole result of map-reduce to another collection.

Comment: is adding the document in other collection also considered as modification ?

Comment: Any modification in any collection

Comment: Any other alternative to achieve above result ?

Comment: I am not fully aware of your needs. You could put entire output of MapReduce to another collection using 'out' and 'merge' option. Alternatively you could parse output in your code or mongo shell and insert whatever you need to any collection

Comment: In terms of output of Reduce phase, it produces/return single value. But our requirement is to produce multiple values ( as per our above use case) that's the reason we are trying to insert document in reduce phase.

Comment: You could return array of your values as property of reduce output. Something like return { arr: [{},{},{}]};